# Implementation of a correlation alogrithm

Tags: signal

I have been reading a document that implements a cross correlation between two signals by first multiplying them and then doing an FFT of the product. The implementation by multiplying the FFTs of the two signals is understandable since convolution in time domain is multiplication in frequency domain. But how multiplication in time followed by an FFT of the product is the same as cross correlation is not clearly understood.Could somebody help out please?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or perhaps http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Probably should be moved, but I would tell you what I know.

As far as I know, the correlation is by definition the convolution between two signals, that in the frequency domain becomes the product of the transforms. For the same reason, the auto-correlation is the convolution of the signal with himself, or the square of the Fourier transform.

So, it should be the product of the transforms, and not the transform of the products.